# Is it possible to mount VHD image over smb with ftp backend?

Tags: linux, windows, ftp, smb, vhd

Let's say I mount remote ftp server folder to a local folder using fuse. Then I setup samba and create a share pointing to local ftp folder. Can I place a VHD image on that share and then mount it in windows or will the ftp backend side of things play up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Ftp does not support real-time bi-directional sync.